# Where is `npm link` registring commands on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, npm, symlink, npm-link, oclif

### Background

I have an NodeJS oclif CLI named "mydemo" and ran `npm link` to register and execute the program's commands globally. After I ran `npm unlink mydemo` to unregister the command, when I type the program's name, I get the error below.

```sh
$ mydemo
bash: /home/eric/.nvm/versions/node/v15.8.0/bin/mydemo: No such file or directory
```

### Expected output

```sh
$ mydemo
mydemo: command not found
```

### Question

How does Linux still know to look in the ".nvm" directory for this command if I've unlinked it?

### Attempts to figure it out

- Ran `npm unlink`
- Ran `npm uninstall -g mydemo`
- Ran `which mydemo` (no output)
- Searched for symlinks (maybe I didn't search the right place)

... it still searches that specific ".nvm" directory.

### Environment

- Ubuntu 20
- nvm 0.37.2
- node v15.8.0
- "@oclif/dev-cli": "^1.26.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. The command was cached in the shell session, possibly in the $PATH variable. It cleared in a new user session.